# sccm 2012r2 client is offline

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, sccm-2012-r2

I have a primary site server and some client that was installed during client push installation .
but just now I swa that one of my client is not getting policy from site server .I ran client notification and client download policy .after a while it says the client is offline .
How can I make that online again?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the computer is on? I am not sure what the exact threshold is but if a client does not check in for a predetermined period of time it will move into an inactive state.

If you know the machine is on, your best bet initially in my experience is to simply reinstall the client. If that does not work, you will need to dig into the logs and state of the client install.